# Specify order for Listener execution?

Tags: java, swing, listener

Is there a way to specify order in which registered XXXListeners are executed? More specifically KeyListeners.

Comment: Listeners can be added and removed at runtime and are by definition non sorted. Maybe explain why you want to do that and someone can suggest a solution to the original problem.

Comment: The order is implementation-dependent and may change in the future. You should **NEVER** rely on any order of execution of your Listeners. In addition, using KeyListeners should be avoided in favor of ActionMap/KeyMap when possible (i.e. most of the time).

Comment: the sequence of listener notification is explicitly _unspecified_ (in an early 1.1 spec about the event mechanism, lost the link). So it's an implementation detail, better not rely on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyListener`s are chained internally in `Component`, there doesn't seem to be any way to specify order apart from the order in which they are added.

Comment: order in which they are "added" != "notified" Or in other words: this is not an answer to the question ;-)